# Retrieve Venues where there are No Events on that day Only

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a *venues* table where there are no *events* placed on that day.

This is how I would retrieve an event:

```
SELECT
    events.*,
    venues.*,
    party_types.PARTYTYPE
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
GROUP BY events.ID
```

Where **$DATE_START_SELECTED** and **$DATE_END_SELECTED** are PHP variables that basically say *Take all events between Date1 and Date2*.

This is how I currently retrieve venues:

```
SELECT
venues.*
FROM venues
GROUP BY venues.VENUE_NAME
```

How would I go about retrieving *all venues* where **there are no events held on that day** (dependent on the PHP variables)?

Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
venues.*
FROM venues
LEFT JOIN events ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID  AND start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
where events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL
GROUP BY venues.VENUE_NAME
```

Comment: if the start_datetime and end_datetime are in the events table you won't have any date to compare with if there are no events on that day, plus the  venues.ID will not be null since it's in the from clause and is an left join.

Comment: Hi Soaica, thanks for your help, however this returns 0 rows :/

Comment: I believe that the "VENUE_LOCATION" is a foreign key, therefore it can't be null if there is an event, plus if the "events.VENUE_LOCATION" was null this join "events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID" would return nothing.

Comment: but this doesn't give a specific date, if a venue had en event in 2011 that venue won't show in this query even thou there isn't any event today.

Comment: if there are no events for a venue then events.VENUE_LOCATION will be NULL because of the LEFT JOIN

Comment: The date conditions can be placed inside the ON condition (left join events on events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID AND start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'). It will try to match events in the specified date range

Comment: Hi, I just noticed what Euclides Mulémbwè has said. if there are any Events in the future or past in the database, the venue is automatically discarded from the query.

Comment: yes, but the query you posted will get events from last year as well so the venue location wont be null for that event, but what he wants to know is what venues don't have any event on a specific date.

Comment: that also won't work because the start and end date are in the event table and since there shouldn't be a matching line, the dates would be null.

Comment: Should work fine. The WHERE contains only one condition : events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL. If the dates will be null then so will events.VENUE_LOCATION.

Comment: I posted a possible answer, please try it.

Comment: Your answer does the same thing as my query. You just used a subquery instead of joining! I belive that method is slower on large datasets :P

Comment: not quite the same thing, if events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL then "start_datetime" and "end_datetime" will also be null, so you can't compare it to any date. if the events.VENUE_LOCATION is null then it means that there is no event therefore no start or end_datetime.

Comment: @pufAmuf is the VENUE_LOCATION column a foreign key? if it is, than it can't be null if there and ID for the event, plus Soaica Mircea is doing this "LEFT JOIN events ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID  AND start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED' AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
where events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL", if (events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL) then this join (events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID) will always compare null to venues.ID.

Comment: Thank you Euclides for your help, however your code did remove a venue which had an event in the past. However, I am still thankful for your work!

Comment: VENUE_LOCATION is a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
venues.*,
FROM venues 
LEFT JOIN events
ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL
```

Comment: I believe that the "VENUE_LOCATION" is a foreign key, therefore it can't be null if there is an event, plus if the "events.VENUE_LOCATION" was null this join "events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID" would return nothing.

Comment: Exactly.  He's looking for all venues where the join to events fails.

Answer (score 1):

try this, I believe it won't perform very well, but it will give the correct answer.

```
SELECT
venues.*
FROM venues
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT
    VENUE_LOCATION
    FROM events
    WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
    OR end_datetime < '$DATE_START_SELECTED')
GROUP BY venues.VENUE_NAME
```